# How to run multicore on a macbook pro with 2 cores?

Tags: r, multicore

So this bit of code:

```
library(plyr)
library(doMC) 
registerDoMC(cores=2) 
x=1:100
llply(x, some_function, .parallel=TRUE)
```

fails with an error like so:

```
__THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__ ()
```

the error disappears when I run R from terminal. So it's something about the GUI that breaks it. Unfortunately, I share this code with collaborators and so I can't ask them to run it from the terminal.  This [forum post](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-mac@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg04234.html) says *It looks as if this problem w/ the doMC backend was coming from my having been sourcing the "/Applications/R.app/Contents/Resources/GUI- tools.R"* but I am not intentionally doing that in R.app. Is there any way to turn off this conflicting behavior?

My Mac specs: Also running R GUI 2.13.1. OSX 10.7.1, doMC Version 1.2.3 with 64bit R.app. Also have a MB Pro 2.53 with Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: You're running this code from raw GUI, right?

Comment: Unable to reproduce in R 2.13.1 with OSX 10.5.8 using doMC ver 1.2.3 within the 64bit R.app

Comment: I should probably add to my setup description: MacBookPro5,3 w/ Intel Core 2 Duo   (... and you should add to your description.)

Comment: Also running R GUI 2.13.1. OSX 10.7.1, doMC Version 1.2.3 with 64bit R.app. Also have a MB Pro 2.53 with Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: Do you also have the GUI-tools.R called in your .Rprofile?  What happens if you take that out?

Comment: I don't. I've even disabled my .rprofile and it still happens.

Comment: This is a hack, but as it seems progress isn't being made in debugging your situation: Why not just put that code in an external script and use `Rscript` to call it?  If need be, the data can be saved or you can use one of the nice packages for sharing objects between R instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask on R-SIG-Mac if you want real answers ;). This has nothing to do with the GUI tools, it has to do with the Cocoa running event loop in the children - see ?multicore for the warning about GUIs. You may want to update to more recent multicore which disables the event loop in the GUI (if possible). Also avoid any Quartz graphics calls in the code you run.